# Apache2 proxy to serve a static page

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, static-content

I would like to stand up an apache2 proxy server (proxy.domain.internal 10.2.2.10) to do the following:

1. Transparently serve local content (http://proxy.domain.internal:8085/arbitraryContent) to local clients.
2. Forward all other requests to the static page at http://proxy.domain.internal:8085/notice.html

I had the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://proxy.domain.internal:8085/notice.html [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Without the proxy set, clients can browse internal links on proxy.domain.internal:8085, but with the proxy they get a 404 error regardless of where they browse.  The proxy setting for the clients is proxy.domain.internal:8888

Can anybody point me to a proper config?  I am not even seeing relevant entries in the access log and the error log is only pointing to /etc/apache2/htdocs which I assume is the inability to get to the error pages.

---

Answer (score 0):

This works for my local area 192.168.0.xxx:

`<VirtualHost *:8888>
...
        DocumentRoot /var/www/local/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/local/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
                Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
        </Directory>
...`